# Adding and multiplying combobox/textbox

Tags: excel, vba

If ComboBox3.Value Like "*Chard*" And ComboBox4.Value Like "*Days*" Then * texbox4.Value

This is the first part of the code that I have but I am stuck. I want it to read the value in combo box 3 and then read the value in combo box 4, then to read the value in text box 4 and multiple this by a value which is stored on a sheet within the workbook.

How do I go about this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty close already.

```
if combox3.value like "Chard" And Combobox4.value like "Days" then
    textbox4.value = textbox4.value * range("A1") ' or whatever range you choose.
end if
```

Answer (score 0):

this is what ive got so far:

If combox3.Value Like "Chard" And ComboBox4.Value Like "Days" And ComboBox9.Value Like "Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday" Then
    TextBox4.Value = TextBox4.Value * Range("B2") ' or whatever range you choose.
End If
End Sub

im getting run time error 424 now, object required. I cant seem to get textbox 4 to multiply by the value in sheet 3 cell B2?